# How do i install a python script like package manager does?

Tags: python, installation

If i try to install a package from package manager in any kind of Linux based system, it is installed, adds a shortcut to system menu and so on. It removes the whole package if i type:

```
"sudo apt autoremove 'packagename'"
```

How can i do that kind of stuff for my own python script? How is it possible to create a shortcut and install the script for my own system? So i can quickly access it from system menu and uninstall it with one command as i want? I dont want to add a shortcut manually or dont want to distribute my program in a repository, just want it to act like a regular packaged program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "package" contains dozens of small distro-specific configuration snippets and scripts to integrate the packaged program with the rest of the system. Some parts of this are specified in distro-neutral standards such as http://freedesktop.org/ but the most accessible documentation will probably be in the packaging manual for your particular distro. For Debian and derivatives (Mint, Ubuntu, etc) the authoritative documentation will be the Debian Developers' Reference, but you might want to start with the [Debian Wiki "Packaging" page](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging).

For your specific question about creating a menu entry or a desktop shortcut, you want a [`.desktop` file](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Howto_desktop_files/).

Creating a `.deb` file for a simple Python script and a `.desktop` file for it is eventually a fairly simple task, but getting a grasp of the entire stack from Python packaging basics to distributing it from a simple PPA or local file system is probably going to take some effort. If you already have a correct `setup.py` file, the next step would probably be to wrap it with a simple `debhelper` package, then add a `.desktop` file once you have that working.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using linux just use aliases . That is the easiest way . `alias aliasname='commands'`

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import os

def alias_writer(bashrc, a_name, a_command):
    with open(bashrc, 'a') as bash_profile:
        bash_profile.write('alias ' + a_name+'='+a_command+'\n')
    os.system("source " + bashrc)

alias_writer('/Users/user/.bash_profile', 'runpy', 'python')
```

That write a alias 'runpy' and runs the python console. In terminal you would write 'runpy'. Also add a alias for this file to create a alias :)

Comment: This is horrible for a number of reasons. The `os.system()` call does not do anything useful (it runs a shell and then immediately exits; this cannot affect the parent shell from which you are running Python). While being able to run something from the command line is probably superior in a number of ways, the OP is actually asking about how to create a GUI launcher (and aliases are an ugly hack anyway; use functions).

Comment: Doing all this in Python would make sense if your code took reasonable precautions to avoid adding code which is already in the file, but as it is, this is just a longwinded way to say `alias numpy='python3 -m numpy'; alias numpy >>~/.bash_profile`